# Batch FIle and Winscp to download files from SFTP Server

Tags: batch-file, automation, batch-processing, winscp

I want to run a batch script to do the following :

Using WinScp:

1. connect to sftp server
2. change local directory
3. download all files

connecting with :

winscp.com sftp://HOST.com:2222/download/ -privatekey="C:\SFTP keys\PRIVATE-KEY.ppk"

allows me to use the following commands to successfully achieve this :

- lcd "c:\DIRECTORY"
- get *.*

how do I add the above commands to the command line command so that I can automate it from a batch file?

Thanks

Comment: my only question how you delete from the other side after you get it?

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the duplicate.

Comment: *how you delete from the other side after you get it?*: That's a different question, ask it separately. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Though your question is most likely already answred here.